# Why objects of prepositions are called "objects"?

Tags: prepositions, objects

Textbooks of English grammar say that there are three types of objects: direct objects, indirect objects and objects of prepositions.

But I cannot understand why the former two types (a major element of a sentence) and the last one (just nouns after prepositions) are treated equally. Are objects of prepositions called "objects" just because no other proper word was found, or is there a practical meaning?

Comment: Object: Grammatical sense of "a member of a sentence expressing that on which the action of the verb is exerted" is from 1729. https://www.etymonline.com/word/object

Comment: @user121863 So that means objects of prepositions were not called "objects" at that time?

Comment: The prototypical preposition takes an NP as complement: "in the garden", "to Paris" etc. The distinction in clause structure between an object and a predicative complement applies to PP structure too. The NPs "the garden" and "Paris" are thus objects, and the contrast of transitive vs intransitive can be applied to prepositions as well as to verbs. "In" for example, is transitive in "She stayed in the house", and intransitive in "She stayed in".

Comment: @BillJ Thank you... your explanation is the most satisfying.